# kubernetes ErrImagePull after I manually "docker pull"

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

When I `helm install stable/hadoop`，it reports this error:

> Failed to pull image "danisla/hadoop:2.9.0": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

so, I manually `docker pull danisla/hadoop:2.9.0`, but it didn't work.

The `imagePullPolicy` is `IfNotPresent`

Comment: Where did you set the `imagePullPolicy`? Did you edit the chart online?

Comment: I didn't edit, the default `imagePullPlolicy `is `IfNotPresent`

Comment: Where is your cluster hosted? Do you the image the on all the nodes?

Comment: I did not put the image on each node. It works now, very grateful for you help

Comment: Where are you running the `docker pull` command?  The approach you're trying to take requires manually pulling the image on every node where the image could potentially run; this is manageable in single-node setups (minikube, kind, Docker Desktop) but not on anything larger; you all but need some sort of container registry to effectively use Kubernetes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pull the image on all nodes with your approach.

Ideally you need to setup the registry to work with your cluster. If you need to authenticate to your registry, you can can create a secret and use `ImagePullSecret`.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/#log-in-to-docker